# Forward declaration of type defined with `using`

Tags: c++, boost, forward-declaration

Let's assume I have such situation:

```
//A.hpp
#include "B.hpp"
#include "C.hpp"
#include "D.hpp"

using A = boost::variant<B, C, D>;

//B.hpp
#include <memory>

class A;
using AA = std::unique_ptr<A>;
```

This give me following error: `error: typedef redefinition with different types ('boost::variant<B, C, D>' vs 'A')`

I can't omit `#include`'s in `A.hpp` because `boost::variant` wants complete types.

How to forward declare `A` which is defined with `using`?

If it is not possible, I would like to now, how to solve my problem avoiding a lot of boilerplate code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can't omit `#include`'s in `A.hpp` because `boost::variant` wants complete types.

That's not relevant since you're not instantiating a `boost::variant` here.

Go ahead and omit the `#include`s.

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d529ed0c39ffc7f))

Then your problem evaporates:

> How to forward declare A which is defined with using?

Don't. Use `using` again or, better yet, hoist the `using` statement into its own header that may then be included wherever it's needed.

Comment: I get error: incomplete type 'B' used in type trait expression from the place where I instantiate the variant.

Comment: @justanothercoder: Nowhere in your question did you instantiate it. You're talking about a completely different scenario than the one about which you asked. Notice that in my live demo I have brought in definitions for `A`, `B` and `C` by the time the variant is actually instantiated.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I have understood what my problem was.

Answer (score 3):

Just replace `class A;` in B.hpp with `using A = boost::variant<B, C, D>;`

The `using` keyword does not forward-declare anything; it just declares a type-alias. So, when in "A.hpp" you include "B.hpp", you put into the same translation unit both a forward declaration of a class named A, and the declaration of a type alias named A.

Comment: So I will need to include `C.hpp` and `D.hpp` in `B.hpp`. Actually I need that in all of three files. So each file will include each other. Is this really the only solution?

Comment: @justanothercoder Well, creating such circular references is not the solution at all :). Can't you just put the declarations of B, C and into the same header?

Comment: @justanothercoder: [No, you don't need to do that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/75f6d7bc4aeb4468). Where did you hear that?

Comment: I get `error: incomplete type 'B' used in type trait expression` from the place where I instantiate the variant.